# What datatype to use when signup can be with either email or phone-number in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, data-modeling, sqldatatypes

I have a project where `users` can `signup/login` with either `email` or `phone-number`? I call the column `userName`. I am confused what `datatype` and what `length` to use?

Comment: is userName is the column which either contain email or phonenumber

Comment: Why not let them pick a username specifically?

Comment: `varchar` will work fine, but they will have to format the phone number identically every time. It might be better to make two columns, so you can save both pieces of information for the user and then use a different query based on whether there is an '@' symbol in the login name.